# Intuitive understanding of what a nullhomotopic map is between an $n$ and $m$ sphere.

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, intuition, homotopy-theory

> Let $f: S^m \rightarrow S^n$ be nullhomotopic, where $m \lt n$.

I'm trying to get an intuitive understanding or of what this means for $(m,n) = (0,1),(0,2), \text{ or }(1,2)$.

> $(m,n) = (0,1)$: Two beads on a circle can be pushed to each other and fused or vice versa.
>
> $(m,n) = (0,2)$:  Two beads on a sphere can be pushed to each other and fused or vice versa.
>
> $(m,n) = (1,2)$:  Any loop on a sphere can be shrunk to a point inside the loop.

Does this make sense or are these comparisons misunderstanding a concept?

Comment: It sort of makes sense. Note however that for $(m,n)=(1,2)$ it isn't clear what "a point inside the loop" means. What is inside and what is outside? I think that more intuitive is to think about rubber loop on a sphere which you can move over the sphere to contract it to any point.

Comment: Note, in particular, that there are surjective mappings from the loop to the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a nullhomotopy intuitively means you can homotope the image to a point (a constant map). One way to intuitively understand this is that $f : S^m \to S^n$ is nullhomotopic if there is only a trivial way of 'wrapping' $S^m$ on $S^n$ (although this analogy is better when $n \geq m $). You can 'shrink' two dots ($S^0$) to a point, and you can shrink a circle to a point on $S^k, k \geq 2$. Note this explains the intuition behind other homotopy groups of spheres too. For example, the Hopf map from $S^3 \to S^2$ basically says that there is a non-trivial way of wrapping the 3-sphere around the 2-sphere. Does this make sense?