# Intuition behind nullhomotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

The definition of nullhomotopic is that: a map $f:X\to Y$ is nullhomotopic if $f$ is homotopic to a constant map i.e. there exists a homotopy $H(x,t):X\times I\to Y$ s.t. $H(x,0)=f(x),H(x,1)=x\mapsto y_0$. However, I have trouble understanding its intuition behind it. From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2354919/intuitive-understanding-of-what-a-nullhomotopic-map-is-between-an-n-and-m-sp), it said that "nullhomotopy means we can homotope the image of $f$ to a point". To my understanding, that means we can deform $Y$ continuously to a point. Is it correct?
Here are two examples I know the proof but try to figure out the intuition:

1. Any continuous map $f:X\to Y$ where $Y$ is contractible is nullhomotopic. (Proved by construction)
2. $f:S^n\to S^1$ for $n>1$ is nullhomotopic. (Proved using covering space)
3. Any continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}P^2\to S^1$ is nullhomotopic.

Even though I can write down the proof exactly, I have trouble understanding the intuitions behind them. Would someone like to explain it to me?

Comment: We're not deforming $Y$, we're deforming $f:X \to Y$. One intuition is that there is enough "room" to make $f$ trivial.

Comment: @QiZhu, would you mind explaining what you mean by "room"?

Answer (score 2):

> it said that "nullhomotopy means we can homotope the image of $f$ to a point". To my understanding, that means we can deform $Y$ continuously to a point. Is it correct?

No, that is wrong. First of all the quoted sentence talks about image, $Y$ is not necessarily the image (or equivalently: $f$ is not necessarily surjective). But more importantly, even when $f$ is surjective this is wrong. This intuition is dangerous, because there are nullhomotopic maps with non-contractible images. In fact you can find such map for any non-contractible Peano space (a space that is an image of $[0,1]$, or equivalently compact, connected, locally connected metric space) $X$, e.g. any sphere $S^n$. By taking any surjective curve $[0,1]\to X$ and concatenating it with the inverse of itself.

A better intuition, in my opinion, is to think about homotopy as a path inside the space of continuous functions $C(X,Y)$. This is even formally true when $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff. With this approach "$f$ is nullhomotopic" simply means that there is a path from $f$ to some constant map.

So for example your point 1 would mean: if $Y$ is contractible then $C(X,Y)$ is path connected. Point 2 means $C(S^n,S^1)$ is path connected for $n>1$. Point 3 means $C(\mathbb{R}P^2,S^1)$ is path connected.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for an intuitive definition of a the null homotopy property of a function $f$ that maps points in a space $X$ to points in space $Y$. The first abstraction that you need to conceptualize is that many such maps that fit the definition of $f$ are possible and that the set of all possible maps is itself a space.  For example consider the map $f_0$ defined by all points in $X$ are mapped to a single point $y_0$ in $Y$.  Another such map $f_1$ is one where all points in $X$ are mapped to a different point $y_1$ in $Y$.

The second abstraction you will need to understand is that if a continuous path from $y_0$ to $y_1$ exists, then there is a set of functions $f_t$ mapping all points $X$ to a single point along the path at each $t$.  This identification would start at $t=0$ with the single point $y_0$ and $y_1$ at $t=1$.  That set of functions $f_t$ parameterized by the variable $t$ is itself a path through the space of all maps $f$. So one says that the map $f_0$ is null homotopic to the map $f_1$ because final the map $f_1$ is a constant map.

Similarly one might consider a more general starting map $f$ and path-connecting all points in $Y$ that are in the image $f(X)$ to a single point $y_1$ in $Y$. Then the parameterization by the variable $t$ along these paths evolves the function towards the constant map at $t=1$. That parameterization is a null homotopy.